# BIMI, Gravatar. Sender image still not showing up in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, bimi

I have set up BIMI perfectly for my domain according to mxtoolbox, https://audiodiary.ai

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=bimi

I have also set up Gravatar for multiple domains.

I use Google Workspace to manage my emails and have set an avatar there too, which works when sending images from the Gmail interface.

The image does not work when I send mail from my node server via postmark

Everything I find online says that I will need to pay $1500 plus lawyer fees to get the image working, but I have found emails in my inbox (i.e. tide.co, otta.com) who send me automated email, but have no BIMI at all according to mxtoolbox.

How can I have a sender image in gmail?

Answer (score 2):

I found two things that need to be addressed:

1. For BIMI to work, you need **SPF, DKIM, and DMARC** to be configured and aligned. In your case, **DKIM** is not properly configured: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dkim
2. Checking **MX** records shows the following *warning*. While I'm not sure if it requires fixing for BIMI to work, I would suggest to do so just in case. You can check it on this tool: https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/

   The domain kdk4snd7ejgdyf6y323yp76rmrwkrdomhwsxkftju6jpujkrephq.mx-verification.google.com does not exist

Also, your records are only allowing mails sending from Gmail. If you are using a different server to send, you have to include their details on your dns records.